# What is meaning of "Fleischbauchnabel"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In book "Gregs Tagebuch Gehts noch?" has following sentence:

> Das fanden wir aber alle zu offensichtlich, weil George einen ausgeprägten Fleischbauchnabel hat, den alle anderen AUF DER STELLE erkannt hätten.

What does word Fleischbauchnabel has meaning here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a composition of *Fleisch* and *[Bauchnabel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauchnabel)* (belly button, navel).

On [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauchnabel#Nabelanomalien) you find also a definition of Fleischnabel (Nabel and Bauchnabel are just two names for the same.)

> Haut- oder Fleischnabel: Hier tritt der umgekehrte Fall ein: Die Bauchhaut erstreckt sich auf die Nabelschnur, sodass sich nach deren Abfall ein stumpfförmiger Nabel bildet und dieser das Hautniveau mehr oder weniger deutlich überragt.

Normally the navel goes into the belly, with a *Fleischnabel* the navel is (partly) over the skin of the belly.

The medical name seems to be [Sarkomphalos](http://medizin.deacademic.com/17570/Sarkomphalos).